# Filemaker Scripting + MailChimp API

Tags: api, scripting, mailchimp, filemaker, scripting-language

I am currently creating a CRM solution in Filemaker and would like to link the contacts with a Mailchimp List.

I have a BG in Web development and am relatively new to scripting so I'm unsure exactly how to get started.

Does Filemaker have a specific Scripting language? If so, I can't figure out what that is...

What I would MOST like to know though is, how do I get started in using the Mailchimp API, what is needed to do so? How do I connect to the API?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileMaker does have a Scripting Language. Look under the "Scripts" menu.  Select "Manage Scripts" That brings up the Scripting Environment within FileMaker. For more info on that see the help

http://www.filemaker.com/help/13/fmp/en/html/create_script.13.1.html#1034729

You can connect to the Mailchimp API using FileMaker scripts. Here is a Modular FileMaker Module that does just that.

http://www.modularfilemaker.org/module/mailchimp/

HOWEVER...

Coming from a web development background, you might be more familiar with thinking of FileMaker like MySQL and using any of the more common web stack tools like 
 PHP, Node.js, python or ruby. You can connect to FileMaker with any of those scripting languages (if your database is running on a FileMaker server). FileMaker has an XML gateway that you can use to connect with any language that can do HTTP requests ( like the ones I listed above ).

For more info see this

http://www.filemaker.com/products/filemaker-server/resources.html

There you will find links to the various ways that you can connect to FileMaker Server, which include the PHP API, the XML publishing gateway, and ODBC

Answer (score 0):

http://kempenautomatisering.com/services/filemaker-mailchimp

Offers a ready product to sync your FileMaker data with MailChimp, they are the only official product on the MailChimp integration directory that offer integrations to FileMaker